# Connect pre-trained model with keras, without top, to custom top model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

i do transfer-learning using keras.
this is what i done:

- load pre-trained model (Mobilnet) without top.
- build model of some layers, input is **output of mobilnet**, and output is softmax (classification mission)
- now i train the top model on the bottel-neck images as input (after go through mobilnet)
- finally i want to connect top model and mobilnet to full model, who gets an images and predict classification.

pseudo code:

```
mnet=MobileNet(include_top=False,pooling='max',
weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))
my_net = bottle_neck = Input(shape=(1024,)) 
some_layer = Dense(100 ,activation='relu')(bottle_neck)  
...
final_layer=Dense(6,activation='softmax')(prev_layers)
```

my goal is to connect the mobilnet, and my net without train all over again
thank u

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

This is covered in the Keras documentation, see https://keras.io/applications/#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes

The key things are to use the base model output as the input of your model (`mnet.output`), and to set reach layer of the base model as `trainable = False`